# Posting Uilocalnotification dynamically after some validation of code before triggerring the notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uilocalnotification

I want to set a UILocalNotification in my app, I will be setting the firedate to the notification for 6 hours and set to the application, but before notification is triggered i have to validate my own condition, if it satisfies the condition i should not post the notification, else I have to post the notification. How can I handle this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Post the `UILocationNotification` scheduled for 6 hours in advance. Use the `userInfo` dictionary to mark the notification as not validated (ex: `@{@"Validated": @NO}`).

In your `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` handler, check for the `Validated` flag. If it is not validated, do so. If it passes validation, repost the notification one millisecond in the future.

If a validated notification comes in, show it.

Basic idea:

1. Post the notification in a **non-validated** state, scheduled for 6 hours later.
2. Receive the notification, check if it is validated.
3. If not validated, validate and repost immediately in a **validated** state.
4. If it is validated, show the notification normally.
5. Discard all notifications that do not pass validation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still  it does not satisfy my requirement @Silo

Comment: Can you explain why? I must not be understanding your requirement.